# In nilpotent groups, does $\forall a\in G [a,[a,x]]=1$ imply $\forall a\in G [a,x]\in Z(G)$

Tags: group-theory, nilpotence, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be a finitely generated torsion-free nilpotent group. Let $x\in G$.

Assume that $[a,[a,x]]=1$ for every $a\in G$.

Does it follow that $[a,x]\in Z(G)$ for every $a\in G$?

My feeling is that the answer should be "no". My intuition is that if you take $K$ to be a finitely generated *free* nilpotent group of class $3$, take $x$ to be one of the generators of $K$, and let $G$ be the quotient of $K$ by the normal closure of the set of elements of the form $[a,[a,x]]$ (running over $a\in G$), then I see no reason this normal closure would contain all elements $[b,[a,x]]$ (running over $a,b\in G$). But this is, of course, not a proof.

**NOTE**: If there is a counterexample $G$, I would especially like to have a counterexample of class $3$.

Comment: These groups are called $2$-Engel groups, and there are many known results about them, one of which is that $2$-Engel groups are nilpotent of class at most $3$, which suggests that the answer to your question is no. Sorry I have no time to find references at the moment.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks. I read the definition now. There seems to be a difference: I fix $x$, while in $2$-Engel groups it's "for every $x$". Nevertheless, I think indeed that a nilpotent group of class $3$ which is not $2$-Engel would give the desired counterexample.

Comment: Ah yes I see there is a difference. You mean a nilpotent group of class $3$ which is 2-Engel would be a counterexample. I will look for one later.

Comment: I am afraid that this approach will not answer your question. It turns out that $2$-Engel groups satisfy the identity $[x,y,z]^3=1$, so $2$-Engel groups with no elements of order $3$ are nilpotent of class at most $2$. Note that elements $x$  with the property you describe are called (right) $2$-Engel elements.